# python replace character without replacing already replaced characters

Tags: python, string, replace

I try to replace characters in `mystr = 'AC'` according to dict `d = {'A':'C', 'C':'B'}`. However, ***I will not replace all at once.*** I will replace characters in Key order one by one (I do some calculation after each replacing). What's more important, ***I can't replace characters which already replaced.***

For example: at first step, I replace `'A'` with `'C'`, then I got `'CC'`. I use `'CC'` do some calculations, then go to the next step. At the next step, I will replace `'C'` with `'B'`. Although I got two `'C'`s in `'CC'`, but the first `'C'` is already replaced. Therefore, I replace only one, then I got `'CB'`

Comment: I am writing it now. Later I will post it.

Comment: You do know that `dict` key order is arbitrary, right?

Comment: hmm, I don't know.  Do you mean ```for key in d.key(): print key ``` print different set at each run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to keep a `flag` list to detect if a character is already changed or not. And as string is immutable, I've made it a list to ease my task.

I think this will help you:

```
mystr = 'AC'
mylist = list(mystr)
flag = len(mystr) * [False]

d = {'A':'C', 'C':'B'}
for key in d.keys():
    for ind, char in enumerate(mylist):
        if flag[ind] == False and key == char:
            mylist[ind] = d[key]
            flag[ind] = True
    #do some calculation 

mystr = "".join(mylist)

print mystr
```

Comment: If the order of replacement matters, you have to use  `collections.OrderedDict([('A','C'),('C','B')])` instead of regular `dictionary`.

Comment: Aince you are just looping over it, a list of tuples works just as well. `for letter, substitution in [('A','C'),('C','B')]:`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need to use list for save result? Or you can calculate after replace. And use [max position in replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) :

```
l = list()
mystr = "AC"
dictionary = {'A':'C', 'C':'B'}

for char in mystr:
    if char in dictionary.keys():
        new_word = mystr.replace(char, dictionary[char], 1)
        l.append(new_word)
```